# Building a Class Schedule

Tags: entries

I am building a site for a martial arts school. I want to add a repeating schedule to the site from Monday through Saturday so the user can edit classes and times when needed. What would be the best way to do this? Should I use a global, structure or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Will the schedule hold the same content besides date and time?

Comment: Yes, it would hold the same content each week.

Comment: We have a plugin we built to help with recurring schedules.  It is in beta but  stable enough it is being used in production. http://tippingmedia.com/craft/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the field type you could use a [Super Table](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable) field, with columns for the times, the class and the teacher. For the class and teacher column you could consider using an Entries or Categories field, this makes sure the classes are named consistently and you could have links to the classes' description or the teacher's about page.

I would probably create one of these Super Table fields for each weekday and just list them one below the other in your entry type or global set. Is there mulitple rooms or any other reasons to create multiple schedules, than have them in a channel section (ordered by title) or a structure. This could also be handy in case you want to store schedules for each year or season. The user could create the upcoming schedule and it automatically becomes active with the start or the new season (set an expiry date and always pick the latest entry).

Here's an example for school classes:

[image: Schedule with Super Table field]

Comment: Very cool. That's made it much easier and cleaner. Thank you.